# Populate a textarea in a form before rendering with Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new to writing Drupal forms, and having trouble in what seems the simplest thing of the whole process form  namely putting data in a textarea on the form before rendering.

- I am using drupal 7
- I have all necessary files in the module: i.e. .module, and .info ..
- I have used all of these function in my `hook_submit()` but to no avail.

  ```
  Form_state['values'][$myElement=]= $myText;
  Form_state[$myElement=]= $myText;
  form_set_value($form[$myElement], t('$myText'), $form_state);
  ```
- I flushed the cache before every single attempt:

Nothing seems to work. Here is what is in my submit handler:

```
mForm_submit(){
//$form_state['values']['sku_output_fieldset']['sku_output'] = t('$gen_sku_txt');
//$form_state['gen_sku']['sku_output_fieldset']['sku_output'] = t('$gen_sku_txt');
//$form['sku_output_fieldset']['sku_output']['#value'] = t('$gen_sku_txt');
//form_set_value($form['sku_output_fieldset']['sku_output'], t('$gen_sku_txt'), $form_state);
//form_set_value($form['sku_output'], t('$gen_sku_txt'), $form_state);
//form_set_value($form['sku_output'], array('rgb' => '123'), $form_state);
//form_set_value($form['sku_output_fieldset']['sku_output'], array('#default_value' => '123'), $form_state);
//form_set_value($form['sku_output_fieldset']['sku_output'], array('#value' => '123'), $form_state);
//form_set_value($form['sku_output_fieldset']['sku_output'], array('value' => '123'), $form_state);
//form_set_value($form['sku_output_fieldset']['sku_output'], array('default_value' => '123'), $form_state);

$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

all commented code, is what i have tried and did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Are you building the form with Drupal 7 Form API? This is how I've inserted default text into a textarea in a Drupal form:

```
$form['formname_fieldname'] = array(
  '#default_value' => t('Some default text'),
  '#title' => t('Field Title'),
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#rows' => 10,
);
```

Your textarea will be prepopulated with "Some default text"

Comment: That i am doing already and it works fine. but what i need to do is change the text after the submit button was clicked.  the idea is that i take values from other elements in the form and then append them to the value in that textarea and display it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it before rendering, you shouldn't have in a submit function.

You should use [hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) where the `$form` being passed in is the variable you can use to edit the form.

Comment: what i need to do is change the text after the submit button was clicked.  the idea is that i take values from other elements in the form and then append them to the value in that textarea and display it.  so my guess is that using a hook_form_alter would change the content everytime i render the form.. somehow it seems an overkill for a simple task like this... but i will give it a shot